# How can I use a condition on the way of initializing a property in the class?

Tags: php, oop, initialization, conditional-statements

I have a protected property that I need to initialize it dynamically. I mean I need to put a condition on the way of it. Something like this:

```
protected $redirectTo = if ( Session::has("vocher_id") ) ? '/activated' : '/home';
```

But apparently syntax above isn't valid in PHP. Any idea how can I do such a thing?

Comment: If the assignment isn't a constant value, then you need to set it in the constructor, as per the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you are after , here are some examples you might use...

```
<?php

class Foo {

    protected $redirect;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->redirect = (Session::has("vocher_id") ) ? '/activated' : '/home';
    }

    // More Methods that Do other stuff
}
```

OR

```
// Or to make it more "modular" i.e not hardcode things inside the class

class Bar {

    protected $redirect;

    public function __construct($redirect) {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    // More Methods that Do other stuff
}

// Set the redirect when instantiating the class
$bar = new Bar((Session::has("vocher_id")) ? '/activated' : '/home');
```

Or you can create a Setter method (An exercise left for you to do)... There are many ways, so do some reading up on classes etc.